# Problem of SQL Server 2014 - locks on the SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

We upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014. The upgrade was successful.

However, there were problems with optimization. Some queries have started to create locks based on. Often the blockade disappears or whip it but the base does not want to move.

The solution to this problem with us is the MAXDOP change. After the change I do not know what is freeing but everything starts to go like before the jam in the database. I have no idea what to do about it anymore.

Our SQL Server configuration

We have already changed the cost and `MAXDOP` parameters. Doesn't help much. I've optimized queries that cause blockades.

The problem persists all the time. Oddly enough, the `MAXDOP` change helps with this blockage. The system then completely forgives. SQL queries go down and execute.

Comment: what compatability level are you set at?

Comment: and having MAXDOP set to 0 (as in your screenshot) seems like a really bad idea in almost all cases -- it means that one parallel query could use all of your cores. what are the wait stats you're seeing most of?

Comment: Compatibility level: SQL Server 2014 (120)

Comment: so, your queries are now all using a different cardinality estimator than they were under 2008 -- are you able to drop back down to 2008-value (100?) and see if performance returns to what it was pre-upgrade?

Comment: The sql queries that most often block do not last more than 2 seconds. But when they create them, after 3 minutes before they are done. The MAXDOP change makes the problem disappear for a while.

Comment: unfortunately I can't repeat the value 100 until 2008 :(

Comment: this sql lock is on one table until MAXDOP is changed.

Comment: changing the maxdop setting is probably clearing the plan cache, and so alleviating the effects of parameter-sniffing. what's preventing you taking the compat level back down?

Comment: after upgrade level was set to 100, blockades began to arise so we changed to 120, optimized queries but it didn't help. I wonder if somehow you can not change MAXDOP every 15 minutes :). At the suggestion, I will change MAXDOP to 8. We have 4 XEON processors with 4 cores each with 2 threads

Comment: unless your performance problems are _actually to do with parallel queries_, then the changing of the maxdop setting back and forth is just a long-winded way of running `dbcc freeproccache` every so often -- you're not solving the problems, you're masking them. to solve them, you need to understand more about them, which means digging into the issues at a level it's not really practical to do over a forum.

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue can raise due to a lot of reasons. improper Maxdop settings is just one of them.

### Run a health check with Sp_Blitz

- Run *sp_blitz* [sp] (https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitz-overall-health-check) to see what is actually causing your performance bottleneck .
- check for priorities from 1to 50, those are most crucial.
- start fixing them one by one